# Unformatted posts on tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm trying to create my own HTML theme for my blog, I don't know anything about coding, what I've already done I've learned through the internet. and I have a problem that I can't solve.

I fixed my header, but my posts are all in different sizes and formats and deslocated from here I want them to be! I want them to them on the some spot of the header, so it can crowl under it when people scroll through my blog.

[Here is my theme code](http://pastebin.com/raw/s25WD8qf), [and this is my blog.](http://florizer.tumblr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I'm having some trouble understanding what exactly you want but I think you're want them all centered directly below your header. If that's correct then you need to specify it in your code, particularly in the style/css portion. W3Schools does a good job of explaining this and heres a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) so you can take a look. I believe if you simply put  text-align: center;  in your body style as shown below

```
 body {
    color: {color:Body Text};
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:1.8em;
    text-align: center;  
   }
```

That might do it :) I hope that helps